# How to prevent renaming of all classes, interface in dotfuscator

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I am following a MSDN site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977082(v=vs.107).aspx for obfuscating my c# code using the dotfuscator that comes free with VS.

In my C# projects, I have used Dependency Injection (Castle.Windsor) so my application crashed after the obfuscation.

I am thinking about not renaming any of my classes and interface name including constructors but let  their methods, variables rename would solve the problem. I am trying to set the exclusion rule for this in the dotfuscator but still not able to do so.

Could you please let us know how to set the exclusion rule that prevent renaming of classes and interface names along with its constructors but let their methods and variable get renamed in dotfuscator? I am using the dotfuscator that comes with VS2015.

Answer (score 2):

The [Renaming documentation for Dotfuscator Community Edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd551425.aspx) gives general instructions for how to do renaming exclusions like this. It sounds like, in this case, you should add a Type exclusion. That will just exclude the types themselves (and their constructors) without excluding any methods/fields/properties. Type exclusions also apply to interfaces.

If you're trying to exclude all types and interfaces, you can mark the exclusion rule as a regular expression rule, and just use `.*` to match all names. If you're trying to exclude just a subset of types, be careful to specify fully qualified names.

You can use the Preview button to see what will be excluded. (Note that the constructors won't show as being excluded, but they will actually be excluded when you build.)

Finally, the [Pro documentation for excluding by Type](https://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/Dotfuscator/webframe.html#Selecting_By_Type.html) has more detail about how some of these features work, so it might help to look there, too. For the most part, the feature is the same between Pro and Community.

Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Actually there are 5 libraries and 2 exe projects in my solution and many classes. It appears that with exclusion rule the some issue fixed but another gets appeared as there are lots of classes that are being used by multiple projects. It appears that I need to find our all the classes that needs to be excluded - so this method seems a bit cumbersome in my case. So, I decided to use "Library mode" for each of the library and exe. Now, it seems to be working.
Is "Library mode" good for this case?

Comment: Library mode automatically excludes all public members in an assembly, so it is probably what you want for your libraries. It will also be fine for the executables, but you might end up renaming less that you would prefer. If so, you can disable library mode and use manual exclusions for those assemblies.